# Magento 2 add custom validation rule

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, validation, requirejs

I'm going crazy here trying to add a custom validation rule to Magento 2. It's impossible to find any useful information about it.

The things I have are as follow:

**1) requirejs-config.js file with the following content:**

```
var config = {
map: {
    '*': {
        experius_postcodenl_validation_rule:'Experius_Postcode/js/validation/postcodenl-validation-rule',
        experius_postcode:'Experius_Postcode/js/widget/postcode'
    }
}};
```

**2) Seperate javascript file:**

```
define([
"jquery",
"experius_postcode", // Custom knockout view model
'jquery/validate',
"validation",
"mage/translate"
], function($,experiusPostcode) {
"use strict";

    $.validator.addMethod(
        'validate-postcode-housenumber-combination',
        function (value) { 
            // My validation
        },
        $.mage.__('No address could be found.')
    );
});
```

This should be enough to add a custom validation rule to the global jquery validator object not?

I Double checked all the file paths. The **requirejs-condig.js** gets loaded (checked in my browsers network tab). No 404 errors on sources whatsoever.

Am I missing something?

ps: don't mind the validation rule itself. Its still a dummy rule

Answer (score 24):

One thing you could try is to add a [JavaScript mixin](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/js_mixins.html):

In `requirejs-config.js` do:

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'mage/validation': {
                'Vendor_Module/js/validation-mixin': true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and `Vendor_Module/view/frontend/web/js/validation-mixin.js`:

```
define([
    'jquery'
], function ($) {
    "use strict";

    return function () {
        $.validator.addMethod(
            'validate-minimum-age',
            function (value) {
                // Some custom validation stuff here
                return true or false;
            },
            $.mage.__('Your validation error message')
        );
    }
});
```

This way your validation rule will extend the original JS validation object and will be available everywhere.

Comment: Would these validations also be available on the checkout?

Comment: @JurģisTomsLiepiņš on my side it's not working. Magento use a different javascript called `validation/rules.js` but using same logic for overwriting is not working

Comment: A fully working example for the checkout here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/209042/add-rule-to-rules-js-magento2/213630?stw=2#213630

Comment: @Giel Berkers : I have tried sample code  it's working fine but  in production mode i'm enabling the minify js that time "validation-mixin.min.js is not created in pub/static/frontend/theme

But in the url it's included like  validation-mixin.min.js

please check and let me know

Comment: This doesn't work

Comment: @Giel Berkers can u please help me on this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/319106/magento2-restrict-cc-number-in-the-form-fields

Answer (score 1):

Based on @Giel Berkers' answer. I had to modify the code a bit to get it working. I have added my code I used in case it's of any help.

app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Vendor_Module/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
config: {
        mixins: {
            'mage/validation': {
                'Vendor_Module/js/validator-mixin': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Vendor_Module/web/js/validator-mixin.js

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'moment'
], function ($, moment) {
    "use strict";

    return function (validator) {
        $.validator.addMethod(
            'custom-validation',
            function (value) {
                // Some custom validation
                return true or false;
            },
            $.mage.__('Your validation error message')
        );
        return validator;
    };
});
```