# Custom validation in PHP

Tags: magento2, validation, customer-address

I added a custom JS validation rule for customer address tax_id field, following [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/190125/magento-2-add-custom-validation-rule) instructions.

But the JS validations can be easely skiped, so how can I reproduce the frontend JS validation in my custom module PHP codes?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

M2 checkout uses web API to communicate with the backend. You can bind your custom plugins(http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html) to any web API service.

For your case it should be `\Magento\Checkout\Api\ShippingInformationManagementInterface::saveAddressInformation`.

So, just create a plugin and put your validation there.

Comment: Hi, I've tried your solution, but aparently without success, I create the plugin in di.xml: `<type name="\Magento\Checkout\Api\ShippingInformationManagementInterface"> <plugin sortOrder="100" name="cpfCnpjValidation" type="Experius\AddressLines\Plugin\CpfCnpjValidationPlugin"/></type>`. And in plugin class, I add a logger, and nothing in logs, I think that is not entering in plugin method, **beforeSaveAddressInformation**, any ideia? Thanks

Comment: Did you clean the cache?