# Script error for validator-mixin

Tags: magento2

I am trying to add a custom validation rule with a mixin to use at the checkout.
I am following [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/213630/51693) tutorial.

So I have:

`Mageplaza/HelloWorld/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js`

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Ui/js/lib/validation/validator': {
                'Mageplaza_HelloWorld/js/validator-mixin': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

`Mageplaza/HelloWorld/view/frontend/js/validator-mixin.js`

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'moment'
], function ($, moment) {
    'use strict';

    return function (validator) {

        validator.addRule(
            'validate-minimum-age',
            function (value, params, additionalParams) {
                return $.mage.isEmptyNoTrim(value) || moment(value, additionalParams.dateFormat).isBefore(moment().subtract(params.minimum_age, 'y'));
            },
            $.mage.__("Sorry, you don't have the age to purchase the current articles.")
        );

        return validator;
    };
});
```

I never call this validation just yet, but when I go to the checkout, I get this message:

```
Uncaught Error: Script error for: Mageplaza_HelloWorld/js/validator-mixin
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Location of

```
Mageplaza/HelloWorld/view/frontend/js/validator-mixin.js
```

should be

```
Mageplaza/HelloWorld/view/frontend/web/js/validator-mixin.js
```