# Magento 2 How to add custom validation rules and apply them?

Tags: magento2, javascript, jquery, validation

I'm trying to modify some validation rules for the State input in shipping address. I want to add an error message if user selects 'Texas'.

I created a mixin for `Magento_Ui/js/lib/validation/rules` in `requirejs-config.js`

I can add a new rule called 'customTexasValidationRule' in the rules collection. However i don't know how to apply this rule to the select input.

I see that i can declare the rules in the select template at `vendor/magento/module-ui/view/frontend/web/templates/form/element/select.html` but i don't want to create a new template file for such a small task.

Is there any quick and easy way to add such a small custom validation in Magento 2?

Comment: try to follow this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/192407/55928 brief description is here https://inchoo.net/magento-2/build-your-custom-form-validation-rule/

Comment: This question is possible duplicate of https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/190125/magento-2-add-custom-validation-rule/192407#192407

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate, my closest answer to this is https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/213630/58644 However as mentioned i don't want to modify the template file for the select input as this is very small and only used in checkout, also this only applies to the state select input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have figured out a way to accomplish this:

I added a mixin for `Magento_Ui/js/lib/validation/validator`:

```
define([
    'jquery'
], function($) {
    return function(validator) {
        validator.addRule(
            'custom-rule',
            function (value) {
                // Custom rule logics here
                return false;
            $.mage.__('Custom error message')
        );
        return validator;
    }
});
```

Then i added this to `etc/frontend/di.xml`, depending the modules you installed, you may have different `LayoutProcessorProvider`, or you may have to use `Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor`, see the link i mention at the bottom for more details, here i have a checkout module to modify my checkout flow called `MyVendor\MyCheckoutModule` so i have this:

```
<type name="MyVendor\MyCheckoutModule\Model\Layout\LayoutProcessorProvider">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="processors" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="additional-billing-address-validation" xsi:type="string">MyVendor\MyModule\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor\Billing\Addtional\Validation</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

Then i added this `Validation.php` file

```
<?php
namespace MyVendor\MyModule\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor\Billing\Additional;

use Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessorInterface;

class Validation implements LayoutProcessorInterface
{
    public function process($jsLayout)
    {
        $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['paymentMethod']['children']['billingAddress']
            ['children']['region_id']['validation']['custom-rule'] = 1;

        return $jsLayout;
    }
}
```

Clear caches and refresh, the validation is now working with my select input in the billing address form.

Note that the structure could be different in `$jsLayout`, as i'm having a module to modify the checkout process so my structure is not the same with stock magento 2 layout.

Big thanks to [Add rule to rules.js Magento2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/209042/add-rule-to-rules-js-magento2/213630#213630) for leading me in the right direction