# How to add js custom field validation?

Tags: magento2, javascript

Does anybody know how to solve this problem:

i'm trying to add custom field validation. Chrome console does not have any errors.

app/code/Company/Module/view/frontend/web/js/view/payment/script.js

```
define(
    [
        "jquery",
        "mage/validation"
    ],
    function ($) {
            console.log('fire1');
        $.validator.addMethod('test-req', function(v) {
            console.log('fire2');
            return false;
        }, 'The amount you entered is too low.');
    }
);
```

src/app/code/Company/Module/view/frontend/web/template/payment/form_additional.html

```
<input class='required test-req' type='text'  data-bind="value: checker" placeholder='Enter the value' minlength='10' maxlength='10'/>
```

On page loading **fire1** always works. But **fire2** is never called. What could be a problem here?

Answer (score 1):

take a look at how Magento 2 validations were added in:
lib/web/prototype/validation.js
That should give you some hints how to add custom validations.

Also take a look here
https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/192407/50597

Comment: The problem is that i did like manual says and it does not work for me. Normally when you press submit button ```src/lib/web/mage/validation.js:_create``` function is called. But in my case does not.

Comment: So, did you fixe the issue yet? If so, please share your fix. Otherwise, go ahead with more queries :).

Comment: i found that even standard validation is not working. Do you know is there some widget for form initialisation?