# How to change the validation message in my account information section in myaccout page in Magento 2

Tags: frontend, customer-account, magento-2.2.5, validation

I wish to add custom validation message in my account information section 
[image]

Please provide me a solution to add custom message in below template.

`vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/form/edit.phtml`

Comment: try this `data-msg-required="Please add confirm password."`.

Comment: IS this possible for shipping address in checkout page

Comment: for which fields? actually yes we can but I want to clear for me.

Comment: Yes it works, But i have added global js, wish to add my custom validate class to Current password

Comment: Try this : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/190125/magento-2-add-custom-validation-rule

Comment: Thank you your solution works for myaccount page,I also need to add custom message in shipping address in checkout page

Comment: I have added answer, please accept if it helps you so it will help others.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this `data-msg-required="Please add confirm password."` for custom validation password and for Validation you can try this.

create `requirejs-config.js` in your module with this code.

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'mage/validation': {
                'Vendor_Module/js/validation-mixin': true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now add create `validation-mixin.js` file at `Vendor_Module/view/frontend/web/js/validation-mixin.js` with this code.

```
define([
    'jquery'
], function ($) {
    "use strict";

    return function () {
        $.validator.addMethod(
            'validate-minimum-age',
            function (value) {
                // Some custom validation stuff here
                return true or false;
            },
            $.mage.__('Your validation error message')
        );
    }
});
```

We can use same way for checkout.